# Remove() with many-to-many relationship doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, many-to-many

Let's say I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship that generated with database first in `edmx` type:

```
public class Teacher
{
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Cours> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{ 
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public byte QtySession { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

 TeacherCourse
{ 
        [key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        [key]
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
 }
//this is many to many relationship table But not generated with edmx
```

In following code I am trying to remove the one of row in `TeacherCourse` table. But the result is not correct(not any actions).

```
SabaEntities sabaEntities = new SabaEntities();
var teacher = sabaEntities.Teachers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TeacherId == teacherId);
sabaEntities.Courses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CourseId == courseId).Teachers.Remove(teacher);
sabaEntities.SaveChanges()
```

This  code running without any error, but the result not corrected, because not remove row mentioned in **TeacherCourse**.
How can I solve it?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? In your `Teacher` entity, do you have a list of `TeacherCourse` or a list of `Course`?

Comment: The version is .Net4.7.2 with databse first.

Comment: in ```Teacher``` entity I have just ```Courses``` list

Comment: Please edit the post to share the code for your `Teacher`, `Course` and `TeacherCourse` classes.

Comment: The .edmx generate `Teacher` and `Course` classes, The `TeacherCourse` is not in edmx list

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Before asking a question read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . In your case  you have to post the classes properties  at least.

Comment: "because not remove row mentioned in TeacherCourse" -- What do you mean? I assume that in the database a record is deleted. If you have a class that's not in the EDMX, don't expect EF to do anything with it.